# Magento: How do i change the status of order after creating Invoice

Tags: magento

I have a problem when i was trying to create invoice. I want to change custom order status at the time of creation of invoice currently when invoice is generated it take automatically COMPLETE status that i want to change to dispatched status. But i am not able to do the same.

Please help me anyone to sort out this issue ASAP.

Thanks,
Nilesh

Answer (score 2):

First you need to understand order states.

After order has been placed, it gets `New` state. At that point, you can Hold it, Ship it, Invoice it or Cancel it, thereby assigning your order `Hold`, `Processing`, `Processing`, or `Cancelled` state, respectively. Once you ship and invoice, your order receives `Completed` state.

Now, each of these states can have a separate status, that you can define yourself if `System -> Order statuses`. In your case, if you want the order to say `Dispatched`, after you are finished shipping and invoicing, you would add `Dispatched` order status and assign it to `Complete` order state. Same goes for any other order states.